# Removing Identical Strings of Text from Excel

Tags: excel

I have a brief question on how to manipulate the text in multiple cells in Excel 2010.

My situation is as follows:  I have about 12 cells arranged in a column.  The length of the string in each cell varies significantly, one cell might have 'abcccd' while another has 'abcccdefghij'.  There is a string of text that is the exact same in every one of these cells and I was looking to remove this part of the string from all cells.  For example, I might want to remove 'ccc' from all cells.  In this way I would be left with only the beginnings of each cell which are unique.  Is there a quick way to tell Excel to remove 'all strings of the form abcdefgh from cells A1...A10' for example?

UPDATE:  On top of the answer below, as mentioned by pnuts it would be really easy just to use the built-in find and replace feature.  E.g. Find 'ccc' replace with ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test data in Column A, result in column B.  Removing the word 'fell' from each entry.

[image]

Place this code in B1 and copy drag down.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("fell",A1)),A1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"fell",""))
```

**

OR...

**

If you want to use VBA try the following code (note that I don't have any error checking and I hard coded the word 'fell')

```
Sub LoopRange()
  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim rRng As Range
  Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

  For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
    rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(rCell.Value, "fell", "")
  Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.  Thanks!